# How to create a stringmap

Tags: opa

When I try to compile an Opa program with

```
m: stringmap(list(string)) = StringMap.empty()
```

I get this error:

```
Function was found of type ordered_map(string, 'a, String.order) but application expects it to be of type  -> 'b.
```

I'd appreciate any hint/help to figure out what's wrong with my code.  TIA,

--
Bahman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to write this:

```
m: stringmap(list(string)) = StringMap.empty
```

`-> 'b` refers to `StringMap.empty()` in the type error you quoted, which is incompatible with your coercion.

Comment: Thanks.  So if I understand it right, `StringMap.empty` is a predefined empty `stringmap` and when I say `m = StringMap.empty` it is just cloned and assigned to `m`?